# Python relative import of an importable module not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, relative-import

I need to use the function MyFormatIO which is a part of the neo library. I can successfully import neo and neo.io BUT I cannot use the MyFormatIO function. `import neo.io` doesn't spit out any errors but `from neo.io import MyFormatIO` returns `NameError: name 'MyFormatIO' is not defined`. How can this be if MyFormatIO is a part of neo.io? I am running python2.7 on CentOS.

Comment: You'll have to show us why you think it's lying.

Comment: Here is an example piece of code from an nih paper where they introduce the package.
`from neo.io import MyFormatIO`
`reader = MyFormatIO(filename=“myfile.dat“)`
`data = reader.read()` Is that what you want?

Comment: No. We want to see the package structure and the contents of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyFormatIO is not a class in neo.io.

http://pythonhosted.org/neo/io.html#module-neo.io

> One format = one class
>
> The basic syntax is as follows. If you want to load a file format that
>   is implemented in a generic MyFormatIO class:
>
> > > > from neo.io import MyFormatIO
> > > >         reader = MyFormatIO(filename = "myfile.dat")
>
> you can replace MyFormatIO by any implemented class, see List of
>   implemented formats

You have to replace 'MyFormatIO' with a class from this list:
http://pythonhosted.org/neo/io.html#list-of-io

A quick way to check this kind of thing in the interpreter is with dir.

```
import neo.io
dir(neo.io)
```

Those are the items that you can import or use from neo.io